# Подключение сервиса оплаты к программной системе

Tags: мобильная-разработка, платежи

Создаю клиент-серверное приложение для одной сети быстропита. Необходимо добавить функциональность оплаты заказа онлайн в мобильном приложении через банковскую карту.

Подскажите, пожалуйста , как реализуется подключение процессинговых центров для оплаты, с дальнейшей возможностью привязать карту, что бы каждый раз не спрашивалось разрешение на оплату (подтверждение паролем и т.д.)? 
Буду рад каким-либо статьям по этому поводу, какие юридические и программные вопросы необходимо решить для достижения цели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Врядли вы будете работать с процессингами напрямую - очень много волокиты/ответственности, требуются большие объемы транзакций.

Скорее всего, вы будете работать с конторой-посредником, коих великое множество. Каждая контора изобретает свой "самый правильный" протокол, но все они очень похожи и просты в использовании.

"что бы каждый раз не спрашивалось разрешение на оплату" - это называется **"оплата по токену"**

Пример в документации некоторых таких контор:
https://wiki.wayforpay.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=852175
www.liqpay.com/ru/doc/paytoken
payu-api.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1376262

**UPD** fondy.eu ещё одну нашел. Работает в разных странах, поддерживают киви и т.д. но не пишут явно комиссии.

Юридически оформляется либо в ввиде публичной оферты для физлица, либо заключается договор на "прием платежей от населения".

Стоить это вам будет, как правило, 2.5% от суммы платежей.

Comment: Спасибо большое) полезная информация!